# Native Navigation Drawer using IBM worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a hybrid app in Worklight which uses Navigation Drawer in Native. However the navigation drawer will not appear once the webpage is loaded. I can use it only before the 1st index page loading. After that it appears like its been overlapped by the webpage. Anyone suggest answer for this? or how to implement it?

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    WL.createInstance(this);
    WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(this, this);

    WL.getInstance().addActionReceiver(this);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list1);
    mPlanets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanets));

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerlistener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawer,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.open, R.string.close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  Closed: ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  Opened: ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerlistener);
  }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WL.getInstance().removeActionReceiver(this);
}

@Override
public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result) {
    // If I comment this line and stop the webpage from loading then Navigation Drawer appears while swiping
    super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data) {
//Not Required
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (drawerlistener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    int menuItemId = 0;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_icon:
        break;

    case R.id.action1:
        menuItemId = 1;
        break;

    case R.id.action2:
        menuItemId = 2;
        break;

    case R.id.action3:
        menuItemId = 3;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    try {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("itemId", menuItemId);
        WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("menuItemClicked", data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON ERROR");
    }       
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerlistener.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    getActionBar().setTitle(mPlanets[position]);

}
```

Comment: A Navigation Drawer in Android is not supposed to "appear after the webpage is loaded". It is supposed to appear only if the user swipes or taps a button.

Comment: Additionally, you should provide your implementation code, otherwise it is a bit difficult to help if your specific scenario. Provide a sample project showcasing what you are experiencing.

Comment: Finally, you can take a look at the following blog, which implements Android's Action Bar in a Worklight application. Perhaps you can use that approach for the native Navigation Drawer: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/native_ui_in_a_hybrid_application_with_worklight_6.2?lang=en

Comment: In actually, why go native? There are plenty of existing JavaScript-based navigation drawers. You should consider those. Google for it.

Comment: hello @IdanAdar, thanks for replying. Yes regarding  "appear after the webpage is loaded" I'm using it with ActionBarToggle. So when the user swipes the screen from left side or presses the Top left Action bar button it should appear. However the Navigation Drawer does not appear when the web pages are loaded. This is the Code

Comment: @IdanAdar About ActionBar I have already implemented it from the same link and I have noticed that I need to add <preference name="ShowTitle" value="true" /> for the Action Bar. Is there something like this needs to be added for Navigation Drawer? I didn't get much about it while searching. I can write the code for the Drawer in HTML only but I need it for studying purpose and want to get the hang of it.

Comment: The  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="true" /> is added at  (res/xml/config.xml) for your information.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more ideas.

Comment: @IdanAdar ohh! well thanks anyway and lets hope someone answers it!

Comment: @kottart, Any updates here?

Comment: @IdanAdar nope.. still not found solution for it..

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear to me why you are unable to hook your native navigation drawer, a possible workaround (unless you've solved this by now) would be to use a JS-based navigation drawer which would look and do the same.

You can review [this solution](http://bit.ly/1KAQbCq) @ codepen.